# How to install rsync on AIX machine

Tags: unix, rsync, aix

I have a machine running AIX.  I'm looking to install [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) on it.  Does rsync support AIX?  If so, where might I download it?

In case it matters: I will be using rsync to copy a filesystem from my AIX machine to another UNIX machine, so it needs to be compatible with other versions of rsync.

Answer (score 2):

You should download the rsync version from perzl.org. It's a more recent version(3.0.8). It support files with size above 2GB and it is a lot better at synchronizing lot of files.
 [download link](http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.Rsync)

Answer (score 1):

You can download a copy of from the links on this [IBM Toolbox download](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/download.html) page. The page also contains a link to an AIX utility to install the rpm packages and instructions on how install the packages.

Comment: @Lain please be more specific how to download the tool from which link? , did you say that rsync on AIX is diff from linux red hat?

Comment: @yael: on the right hand side of the page I linked to click on `Alphabetically` you'll rind the rsync download in the list.

Answer (score 1):

http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/

Comment: this link also fit for AIX and Linux?

Comment: It's the source code you get there which should compile on AIX.

Comment: With a few exceptions with regard to some file-system specifics, rsync is platform-independent and copying files from AIX to any Linux or other Unix-like OS shouldn't be a problem.